# Is it possible to have an SVG scale to fit parent, maintaining a static fill size?

Tags: html, svg, responsive-design

I am trying to create a paper texture look with svg, which I have working fairly well, using a transparent overlay to add the texture over the basic color of the svg item below it.

However, I notice that the texture scales with the SVG. Since the image is set to the width of the page, on large monitors it becomes extremely stretched and does not look very nice.

Is it possible to have the svg asset scale automatically, with a fixed-size pattern fill?

Here is a codepen with a full example: http://codepen.io/mix3d/pen/jWMPQE

**EDIT: Updated codepen with actual svg, not a theoretical one**

Bonus points if the SVG can stretch with the fill tiling from the center. Thanks!

This is how the SVG looks currently, but the texture scales with the svg
[image: Picture of Codepen]

```
<svg version="1.1" id="paper_svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   viewBox="10 0 1526 407.93">
<style type="text/css">
  .overlay{fill:url(#img1);fill-opacity:1;}
  .circle{fill:#62B4B8;}
</style>


<defs>
  <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="243" height="201">
    <image xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/grtbkje.png" x="0" y="0" width="486" height="402" />
  </pattern>
    <filter id="f3" x="-40%" y="0" width="180%" height="400%">
      <feOffset result="offOut" in="SourceAlpha" dx="0" dy="3" />
      <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="offOut" stdDeviation="3" />
      <feColorMatrix in="blurOut" result="transparency" type="matrix"
        values="0 0 0 0   0
                0 0 0 0   0 
                0 0 0 0   0 
                0 0 0 .5 0"/>
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="transparency" mode="normal" />
    </filter>
</defs>
<g>
   <circle id="Background_Circle" class="circle" cx="280.52" cy="226.67" r="166.67"/>
   <!-- I know I could probably use a filter to achieve the same overlay effect, but this worked for now, duplicate the object with the semi-transparent fill pattern -->
   <circle id="Background_Circle" class="overlay" cx="280.52"  cy="226.67" r="166.67"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: @RobertLongson do you have any examples of that? I'm sure they could be embedded, just want to check. Thanks!

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use a background image? It would be easily centered and tiled.

Comment: @JesseKernaghan The main reason is because the actual svg is not a rectangle, but a polygon with "paper cut" edges

Comment: @mix3d you can't really change the question after it has answers if such a change would invalidate any of the existing answers.

Comment: The actual question didn't change though, just the example? I realized that the first example code was a false detractor and went in an unintended direction... Should I delete then re-ask the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a relative decent workaround, with css media queries.

Because you can embed css media queries in svg, (which will apply based on the svg's size, like when displayed through an img tag), I can then set a differently scaled pattern as the fill element.

I don't know what the memory tradeoff is, if I had, say, 10 different scaled patterns in the `<defs>` tag, with media queries to match, but this works well enough for my application, with negligible overhead. Since the referenced image is the same, it only needs to get loaded once.

**updated codepen: http://codepen.io/mix3d/pen/BjdJge**

```html
    <svg version="1.1" id="paper_svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
       viewBox="10 0 1526 407.93">
    <style type="text/css">
      .overlay{fill:url(#tsmall);fill-opacity:1;}
      .circle{fill:#62B4B8;}
      @media (max-width: 1000px){
        .overlay{fill:url(#tlarge);}
      }
    </style>


    <defs>
      <pattern id="tsmall" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="243" height="201">
        <image xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/grtbkje.png" x="0" y="0" width="486" height="402" />
      </pattern>
      <pattern id="tlarge" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="972" height="804">
        <image xlink:href="http://i.imgur.com/grtbkje.png" x="0" y="0" width="972" height="804" />
      </pattern>
    </defs>
    <g>
       <circle id="Background_Circle" class="circle" cx="280.52" cy="226.67" r="166.67"/>
       <!-- I know I could probably use a filter to achieve the same overlay effect, but this worked for now, duplicate the object with the semi-transparent fill pattern -->
       <circle id="Background_Circle" class="overlay" cx="280.52"  cy="226.67" r="166.67"/>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it.  But you need to remove the viewBox.

Then, if you make the `<rect>` have a width and height of `100%`, you can make the SVG any size you want and the pattern will repeat and fill the entire SVG.

```css
#svg1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#svg2 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern2" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="5" fill=#0000ff />
    </pattern>
  </defs>

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern2);" />
</svg>


<svg id="svg2">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="pattern2" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="5" fill=#0000ff />
    </pattern>
  </defs>

  <rect x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" style="stroke: #000000; fill: url(#pattern2);" />
</svg>
```

Comment: I had anticipated viewbox being a probable place to look, but I'm not sure how to take a polygon with defined vertices and turn them into percentage based points.

Comment: Wait, could it be possible to set all each point in the vertex to a percentage? I'm going to try that now

Comment: I tried, but I don't think %points as polygon vertices works.

Comment: No. You can't use percent coordinates in a `<polygon>` or `<path>`.

Answer (score 0):

As Jesse Kernaghan commented. Is there a reason you don't just use a background image.

(Pen here -> http://codepen.io/thepixelninja/pen/EPgPdx)

ie. create an empty file called pattern.svg (or whatever). then take your svg code and paste it inside, with the addition of the svg header stuff like so...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?><svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" id="pattern" viewBox="0 0 100 100"><defs><pattern id="pattern2" x="0" y="0" width="20" height="20" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="5" fill="#0000ff" /></pattern></defs><rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" style="fill: url(#pattern2);" /></svg>
```

I have removed the stroke from the image as I'll add that onto the div later. We don't want the stroke repeating.

Then save your new svg image file and use it like a normal background image in css. ie...

```
<div id="circles"></div>

<style>
    #circles {

        //always center the circles within the box
        background-position:center;

        //change this to change the size of the circles
        background-size:100px 100px; 

        //point this to where you saved your new svg image
        background-image:url(http://urbanise.net.au/pattern.svg); 

        //set the width of the box
        width:100%; 

        //set the height
        height:500px; 

        //add the border back in
        border:5px solid #000; 

    }
</style>
```

Works like a charm :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The reason using the svg as a background image doesnt work for me, however, is because the actual thing I need this working on is not a rectangle, I only used that as a "get the question written quickly" example. I have updated my codepen with the actual SVGs I am using; the svg shapes themselves are what need the background texture

Comment: If I only needed to worry about the overlayed parts (not the circle), then I could make the top and bottom parts be exactly straight, and then have an absolutely positioned DIV above the svg and use the background texture there... hmmm. Might be a good fallback.